# Buidling Android Apps requires to update to the latsets version of the Gradle Plugin

Tags: android-studio, react-native, android-gradle-plugin

I am currently building an app in React Native (Android Studio) Now I want to generate an APK file to see how it looks on my phone. (emulator is working fine) But I want to see it on my phone also.

Everytime I want to Build -> Build Bundles I am getting an error of the Gradle Plugin. So I can't proceed

I have Upgraded gradle in React native, I have upgraded android Studio and searched a lot on the form and stack without any answers.

[project root]/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'

    } }
```

[project root]/android/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2')

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Still getting the same errror

Comment: Did you update your gradle-wrapper.properties file to the last version?

Comment: This is what I have:

distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10-all.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists

Comment: According to this information [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin) you should use `5.1.1` zip version in your properties. Put this in your gradle properties `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip` instead of 4.10

Comment: Changed it, but still getting the same error

Comment: Does it help to restart my laptop?

Answer (score 0):

In You **APP Modle.Gradle**
try replace this line

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
**To**
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'

Comment: which file is that? I am still  a newbe